# Getting instance of node module while test driving codeal

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

I am creating a factory method where i am returning an instance of a node module

var dal1 = require('../dal/dal1');

var dal2 = require('../dal/dal2');

exports.createDAL(role){

switch(role){

```
case "XYZ": return dal1;
case "ABC": return dal2
```

}
};

Using Mocha as the TDD frame work, When I get the object returned,I get the value of returnObject.constructor.name as object instead of dal1 or dal2. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead with using the node-module 'util'. I was able to get the expected value instead of just 'Object'

I created a DAL object

```
//dal.js

function dal(){

}

dal.prototype.BLAH = function(){
//logic here
}

module.exports = dal

//dal1.js

var inherits = require('util').inherits;

function dal1(){

dal1.call(this);
}

inherits(dal1,dal);

module.exports = dal1;

//similarly dal2.js

//finally in factory
var dal1 = require('./dal1');

var dal2 = require('./dal2');

switch(role){

 case 'XYZ': return new dal1();

 case 'ABC' : return new dal2();

}
```